# Отмерять или отмеривать?

Tags: выбор-слов, точное-словоупотребление

Похоже, что оба варианта допустимы в литературной речи, но являются ли они полными синонимами, или же есть какие-то различия в употреблении?

Comment: Интересное наблюдение. Дополню список: усилить/усилять/усиливать, продлить/продлять/продливать, умолить/умолять/умаливать, усвоить/усвоять/усваивать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из Толкового словаря Даля:

> отмеривать отме́ривать ОТМЕРИВАТЬ или отмерять, отмерять и отмерить
> что, смерять, либо отделить известную меру от чего-либо. Мне отмеряли
> сукна на кафтан, да видно обмеряли. Отмерь и отпусти десять четвертей
> овса да пять ведер вина. Отмерь от угла десять сажень, да поставь
> колышек. Отмерял было, да не отмерил, помешали. Землемер отмерил нам
> по три десятины. отмериваться, быть отмеренным; || кончить измеренье,
> перемерку чего. Отмериванье ср. длит. отмерение окончат. отмер м.
> отмерка ж. действие по глаг. Отмерная земля, измеренная, отделенная
> мерой, отмежеванная. Отмериватель, отмерятель, отмерщик, отмерщица,
> отмеряющий что.

Историческая разновариантность этого глагола, которую можно видеть у Даля, сохранила в современном языке эти две формы, а также отглагольное существительное "отмеривание" (произв. от "отмеривать"). Форма же "*отмерение*" (возможно, производная от "отмерять") похоже что забыта. Даль отмечает различие в употреблении *отглагольных существительных*, отводя существительному "**отмеривание**" обозначение действия как процесса, имеющего некоторую **длительность** (*Отмериванье ср. длит. отмерение*). Если перенести эту особенность на исходный глагол "**отмеривать**", то его логично выбирать в контекстах с акцентом на **процесс**, а не **результат** (в этом случае - **отмерять**). Трудно в современных условиях требовать строгости такого выбора, но я бы разграничил два примера:

> Чем он занимается профессионально? **Отмеряет** ткань покупателям.
>
> Чем он сейчас занят? **Отмеривает** линолеум, чтобы отрезать поточнее.

Comment: Интересное мнение. Слово "отмерение" все-таки присутствует в современном языке. Нечасто, конечно, но есть. _Справедливость — это соблюдение прав человека и **отмерение** воздаяния по заслугам и по грехам_ (А. В. Николаев. Этика средней школы: факультативный курс). _Проверка умения взвешивать на весах, **отмерение** объема воды по мензурке_ (практическая работа по химии ( https://uchitelya.com/himiya/195946-prakticheskaya-rabota-prigotovlenie-rastvora-s-opredelennoy.html)).

Comment: Я бы ещё добавил, что в некоторых случаях используется именно "отмерять", например, когда речь идёт о времени или о промежутках времени.

Answer (score 1):

Смысловая разница между **отмеривает** и **отмеряет** даже не стилистическая (стёрлась), хотя интересно пофантазировать, какой она могла бы устояться в параллельной вселенной с позиции этимологической закономерности, что возможно проявляется в других подобных глаголах.

Для **отмерить/отмерять, отмеривал/отмерял, будет отмерять/будет отмеривать** смысловая разница могла бы проявляться так

```
Он отмерял 10 шагов один за одним. // Возможно, ни одного не отмерил
Он отмеривал 10 шагов один за одним. // Как минимум 9 отмерил
```

Но все равно сдаётся, что он мог отмеривать 10 шагов один за одним, но что-то его сбивало всякий раз, и он переходил к следующему шагу, не отмерив предыдущего.